# How do you secure solid blocking in joists without staggering them?

Tags: framing

I have some construction being done and the plan is to install blocking in the I-joists which I presume will consist of solid blocks of wood about 16 x 11 x 1.5 placed inbetween each joist in a row. Apparently they have a method of installing it so that the blocks are in a perfect row, not staggered, but if so, how could they be nailed in since each block will obscure the nailing point through the web of the joist for its neighbor?

Comment: Watch and be amazed, lol, you don’t have to drive nails straight, in fact a nail driven at an angle has more holding force.

Comment: @EdBeal Face nailing is stronger in every direction than toe-nailing. The Code requires more nails when toe-nailing than face nailing. (See ICC Table 2304.9.1)

Comment: Again you show you can only think in 1 axis Sam I said nothing about toe nailing although that is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called "Toenailing". Basically, you drive the nails at an angle through the block to anchor it into the studs on the side.  More info can be found at [Family Handyman](https://www.familyhandyman.com/carpentry/toenailing-basics/) [image: Example of toenailing]